# Magento2 composer update throws exception

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, composer

When I am running composer update I am faced with the error like:

```
$ ./composer update
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):                                                                                                                                                                        Authentication required (repo.magento.com):                                                                                                                                                                        Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Aborted


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

does anyone face similar issue and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you to enter your magento 2 repo credentials:

- Goto [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/account/)
- Goto your `Profile`
- Goto your `Access Keys`
- `Public Key` is your user name, `Private Key` is your password.
- Enter that information when prompted for it by composer.
- You can permanently store this information in using this method. [How to setup an auth.json file for Composer?](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/743)